# I just want to print my output once

Tags: php, yii, foreach, output, view

I am in the view of business_items table, in which i am getting id and against this id i am retrieving data.Below is my function in Business Items controller.

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $this->layout='main';

    $modelitems = BusinessItems::model()->findAll();  //getting all data of businessitems
    $rate = ItemReview::model()->findAll();  //getting all data of businessitems
    $this->render(
        'test',
        array(
            'rate' => $rate,
            'modelitems' => $modelitems,            
        )
    );
}
```

and here it is my view file, i called test. in which i want to get the mean rating and the business id.

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
$value = $_POST["business_id"];
$matchFound = false;
$ratematch = false;
$save = 0;
foreach ($modelitems as $ba) {
    $bizitems = $ba->id; //getting id of business items 
    $biz = $ba->business_id; //business id from model business items
    if ($value == $biz) { //matching posted id of business with ids in business items table
        $image = $ba->image; //geting image from business items table
        $item_name = $ba->items->item_name; //geting item name from business items table
         foreach ($rate as $ab)  {
             $ratebiz = $ab->business_items_id; //getting business items id from item review
             if ($ratebiz == $bizitems) { //comparing business items id with business items id in item review
                 echo "business items id:" . $bizitems;echo " "; 
                 echo "rating of business items" . $ab->rating;
                 echo "<br.>";
             }
         }
    }
}
```

My output is like this business items id:52 rating of business items4

```
business items id:52 rating of business items5
business items id:52 rating of business items5
business items id:52 rating of business items3
business items id:52 rating of business items3
business items id:53 rating of business items2
business items id:53 rating of business items5
business items id:54 rating of business items2
business items id:54 rating of business items1
business items id:54 rating of business items4
business items id:54 rating of business items3
business items id:55 rating of business items5
business items id:55 rating of business items4
business items id:55 rating of business items3
business items id:55 rating of business items2
```

I want my output like this

```
business items id:52 rating of business items20 //20 is the total rating

business items id:53 rating of business items7  //7 is the total rating

business items id:54 rating of business items10  //10 is total rating

business items id:55 rating of business items14  //14 is total rating
```

what should i do ?

Comment: Are you just asking for a newline character between outputs?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

befor for each loop add the following sum variable and modify loop as below:

```
$sum=0;   
foreach ($rate as $ab){
$ratebiz=$ab->business_items_id;           //getting business items id   from item review
if($ratebiz==$bizitems){                   //comparing business items id with business items id in item review
$sum=$sum+$ab->rating;

}
}
echo "business items id:".$bizitems;echo " "; echo "rating of business items".$sum;
echo "</br>";
```